# unable to view Hyperledger Composer Rest Server home page on browser

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have pulled "hyperledger/composer-rest-server" by running this command "docker pull hyperledger/composer-rest-server" and run it by "docker run --name composer-rest-server --publish 9090:9090 --detach hyperledger/composer-rest-server" . Then after when i tried to access Rest Server on browser by: http://Docker-Default-IP:9090/ , then i am unable to view HomePage. ? And getting connection refused error on browser. Concurrently i am also running the "hyperledger/composer-playground" by running this command "docker run --name composer-playground --publish 8080:8080 --detach hyperledger/composer-playground" and i am clearly able to access Playground on browser by visiting URL: http://Docker-Default-IP:8080/. This is having no problem, but why there is a problem with composer-rest-server ?
I am using DockerToolBox that is good for me. 
Docker version 18.03
Windows-7 Home

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the Port question specifically, you should try `--publish 8080:3000` .

There are some other considerations when running the REST server as a Container [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453704/how-to-run-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-docker-image) asked a few hours after yours has been answered.