# How to run Hyperledger Composer Rest Server docker image?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have pulled hyperledger/composer-rest-server docker image , Now if i wanted to run this docker image then on which port should i expose ? Like mentioned below. 
**docker run --name composer-rest-server --publish XXXX:YYYY --detach hyperledger/composer-rest-server** 
Here please tell me what should i replace for XXXX & YYYY ?

Answer (score 0):

I run the rest server in a container using a command as follows:

```
docker run -d \ 
-e COMPOSER_CARD="admin@test-net" \ 
-e COMPOSER_NAMESPACES="never" \ 
-v ~/.composer:/home/composer/.composer \ 
--name rest -p 3000:3000 \ 
hyperledger/composer-rest-server
```

For the Published Port, the first element is the Port that will be used on the Docker Host, and the second is the Port it is forwarded to inside the container.  (The Port inside the container will always be 3000 by default and is more complex to change.)

I'm passing 2 environment variables into the Container which the REST server will recognise - Namespaces just keeps the endpoints simple, but the COMPOSER_CARD is essential for the REST server to start properly.

I'm also sharing a volume between the Docker Host and the Container which is where the *Cards* are stored, so that the REST server can find the COMPOSER_CARD referred to in the environment variable.

**Warning:** If you are trying to test the REST server with the Development Fabric you need to understand the IP Network and Addressing of the Docker containers - by default the Composer Business Network Cards will be built using *localhost* as the address of the Fabric servers, but you can't use *localhost* in the REST server container as that will redirect inside the container and fail to find the Fabric.

There is a [tutorial in the Composer Docs](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest) that is focused on Multi-User authentication, but it does also cover the networking aspects of using the REST Server Container. There is general information about the REST server [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/integrating-index).